# Redirect to login page if user goes straight to home page without logging in

Tags: typescript, angular2-routing

Suppose we have an application with multiple pages (e.g. Home Page, Login Page, Dashboard etc).

But instead of going through the login screen, the user goes directly to the Dashboard URL.

1. How do we check if s/he is already logged in?
2. If not, logged in, how to redirect to the Login page?
3. How to do it in Angular 2?

Comment: Please format your question a bit - thats a reaaaaaally long sentence...

Comment: Use Angular 2 authentication with auth guard , you can use JWT or any other auth provider like Auth0. https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/18/guards-in-angular-2.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use routing guards for it. There are manyguards in angular like canActivate, canLoad, canActivateChild and canDeactivate. You can use them to prevent an user to go to dashboard and send him to login page if the user is not logged in. For more info about guards 
[check this link:](https://alligator.io/angular/route-guards/)